# Getting overflow encountered in exp error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to run a code that would print me a graph but im running into the following error:

However, if I just type in a numerical value the code runs.

```
M = np.zeros((2,2),dtype='complex')
kz = 2*self.n[i]*np.pi/self.lamdavac*np.cos(self.thetas[i])
delta = kz*self.d[i]
M[0][0]=np.exp(complex(0,-1)*delta)

k = np.array([0,0.0029553,g(lamda0),0])
```

where I defined my variable as a function but every time I run the code I get the following error:

> M[0][0]=np.exp(complex(0,-1)*delta)
>   RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp

How can I fix it?

Comment: you need values less than 709.78271289 in order not to have an overflow. if you have values greater than that then you will have an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import numpy as np
delta=1
output=np.exp(complex(0,-1)*delta)
print(output)
```

so the question is, how much is `d[i]` in your

```
delta = kz*self.d[i]
M[0][0]=np.exp(complex(0,-1)*delta)
```